# Is there a way to change the values in an SSIS dataflow?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I got an issue with SSIS. I got a country field in my dataset, which is a combined field out of 2 tables.
These tables both have different values for country.
1 table uses 2 to 3 letter names for the country, like NL.
the other table uses full country names, like The Netherlands and Netherlands.

My question regarding this: Is there a way i can change these values in my SSIS dataflow so they all become the same?

EDIT

I fixed it by using three REPLACE statements in a derived column
`REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(land,"The Netherlands","Nederland"),"Netherlands","Nederland"),"NL","Nederland")`

Its not the nicest piece of code, but it will get the job done.

Comment: Not without adding either some kind of Lookup-Table, which stores all "translations" (as you mentioned, "The Netherlands" as well as "Netherlands" will have to be changed to "NL"), or a hardcoded task which does this translation - anyways, the lookup table will be the "cleaner" choice.

Comment: Regarding your query - "is there a way to change", the answer is yes. Have a look at the "transformations" in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/integration-services-transformations?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: You'll also need to factor in that this is going to be case sensitive too, so "the netherlands"  won't match